# yeoman fullstack-angular using authentication in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I have a link like this: `<a ng-click="doSomething()">Do something</a>`

In my controller I want to take a different action based on Authentication but I can't figure out the right syntax. I tried the two following ways both are not working.

Trial 1 (always true as it's returning a promiss):

```
$scope.doSomething = function(){
  if (Auth.isLoggedIn) {
    console.log('isLoggedIn'); 
  } else {
    console.log('isNotLoggedIn');
  }
}
```

Trial 2 (Error: Auth.isLoggedIn(...).then is not a function):

```
$scope.doSomething = function(){
  Auth.isLoggedIn().then(function(isLoggedIn){
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      console.log('isLogged');
    } else {
      console.log('isNotLoggedIn');
    }
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trial 1 works for me. make sure you are injecting Auth into your controller, like this:

```
app.controller('somethingCtrl',  ['$scope', 'Auth', function ($scope, Auth) {
```

Then

```
  $scope.doSomething = function(){
    if (Auth.isLoggedIn) {
      console.log('isLoggedIn');
    } else {
      console.log('isNotLoggedIn');
    }
  }
```

will return isLoggedIn

Comment: I had a typo... Thanks for the answer